# Power off detection MSP430

Tags: embedded, detect, flash-memory

I want to detect power supply ON to OFF and want to write important data to internal Flash memory.

Problem is my code is going into ISR when it is OFF to ON instead ON to OFF.

I am stuck at problem

Any help would be appreciated

Here is my code

```
#include <msp430.h>

/*
 * main.c
 */
void write_SegC(void);
void copy_from_FlashC(void);
void PMM_config(void);
void UCS_config(void);

char Flash_Data[20] = {0,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,0,0,0,5,5,5,0,8,8,9,2,3};
char Flash_Data1[20] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

int main(void) {
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;  // Stop watchdog timer
    P1DIR |= BIT0;
    P1REN |= BIT6;
    UCS_config();
    PMM_config();
    UCS_config();

    while(1)
    {
        copy_from_FlashC();
    }
    return 0;
}

void copy_from_FlashC(void)
{
    unsigned int i;
    char *Flash_ptrC;

    Flash_ptrC = (char *) 0x1880;           // Initialize Flash segment C ptr

    FCTL3 = FWKEY;                              // Clear Lock bit
    FCTL1 = FWKEY;
    FCTL4 = FWKEY | MGR0 ;

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        //     *Flash_ptrD++ = *Flash_ptrC++;      // copy value segment C to seg D
        Flash_Data1[i] = *Flash_ptrC++;
    }

    FCTL1 = FWKEY;                          // Clear WRT bit
    FCTL3 = FWKEY | LOCK;                   // Set LOCK bit
}

void write_SegC(void)
{
    P1OUT |= BIT0;

    unsigned int i;
    char *Flash_ptr;                        // Initialize Flash pointer

    Flash_ptr = (char *)0x1880;

    FCTL3 = FWKEY;                          // Clear Lock bit
    FCTL1 = FWKEY | ERASE;                  // Set Erase bit
    *Flash_ptr = 0;                         // Dummy write to erase Flash seg
    FCTL1 = FWKEY | WRT;                    // Set WRT bit for write operation


    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        *Flash_ptr++ = Flash_Data[i];             // Write value to flash
    }

    FCTL1 = FWKEY;                          // Clear WRT bit
    FCTL3 = FWKEY | LOCK;                   // Set LOCK bit
    P1OUT &= ~BIT0;
}

void PMM_config(void)
{
    //unlock PMM
    PMMCTL0_H=PMMPW_H;
    PMMCTL0_L|=PMMCOREV_3;
    //check voltage level
    switch(PMMCTL0&PMMCOREV_3)
    {
            //settings for highest core voltage settings
        case PMMCOREV_3:
            //setup high side supervisor and monitor
            SVSMHCTL=SVMHE|SVSHE|SVSHRVL_3|SVSMHRRL_7;
            break;
    }
    //clear interrupt flags
    PMMIFG&=~(SVMLIFG|SVMHIFG|SVMHVLRIFG|SVMLVLRIFG);
    //setup interrupts
    PMMRIE|=SVMLIE|SVMHIE|SVMHVLRIE|SVMLVLRIE;
    //lock PMM
    PMMCTL0_H=0;
}

#pragma vector = SYSNMI_VECTOR
__interrupt void SYS_NMI(void)
{
    switch(SYSSNIV)
    {
            //core supply voltage monitor interrupt
        case SYSSNIV_SVMLIFG:
            //event to report error
            //set flag
            break;
            //input supply voltage monitor interrupt
        case SYSSNIV_SVMHIFG:
            write_SegC();
            //   Clear_SegC(value);     // For testing only
            //event to report error
            //set flag
            break;
            //core supply voltage monitor delay interrupt
        case SYSSNIV_DLYLIFG:
            break;
            //interrupt supply voltage monitor delay interrupt
        case SYSSNIV_DLYHIFG:
            break;
            //Vacant memory access interrupt
        case SYSSNIV_VMAIFG:
            break;
            //JTAG mailbox in interrupt
        case SYSSNIV_JMBINIFG:
            break;
            //JTAG mailbox out interrupt
        case SYSSNIV_JMBOUTIFG:
            break;
            //SVMLVLRIFGSVMHVLRIFG
        case SYSSNIV_VLRLIFG:
            //clear interrupt flag bits
            //unlock PMM
            PMMCTL0_H=PMMPW_H;
            //clear interrupt flags
            PMMIFG&=~(SVMLIFG|SVMLVLRIFG);
            //lock PMM
            PMMCTL0_H=0;
            break;
            //SVMHVLRIFGSVMHVLRIFG
        case SYSSNIV_VLRHIFG:
            //clear interrupt flag bits
            //unlock PMM
            PMMCTL0_H=PMMPW_H;
            //clear interrupt flags
            PMMIFG&=~(SVMHIFG|SVMHVLRIFG);
            //lock PMM
            PMMCTL0_H=0;
            break;
    }
}

void UCS_config(void)
{
    PMMCTL0_H = 0xA5;
    PMMCTL0_L = 0x03;
    UCSCTL0 = UCSCTL0 | 0x1F00;
    UCSCTL1 = UCSCTL1 & 0x0000;
    UCSCTL1 = UCSCTL1 | 0x0040;
    UCSCTL2 = UCSCTL2 & 0x0000 ; // FLL Divider
    UCSCTL2 = UCSCTL2 | 0x304F ; // for 20 MHz MCLK and 2.6 MHz SMCLK
    UCSCTL3 = 0x0000;

    UCSCTL4 = UCSCTL4 & 0X0000;
    UCSCTL4 = UCSCTL4 | 0X0043;
}
```

Comment: I don't know MSP430 but usually POR (Power On Reset) flag of status reg gives you what you need.

Comment: What do you mean by going off to on vs on to off? The power? Are you using a pin to detect whether power is there? Would you be much more specific please in exactly how you are doing this and exactly what is not working?

Comment: Yes I mean Power On to Off and I am not using any Pin to detect it. I want to detect it internally.

Comment: Has your MSP430 [Supply Voltage Supervisor](https://books.google.it/books?id=VaFeAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA85&lpg=PA85&dq=Supply+Voltage+Supervisor+msp430&source=bl&ots=c1ARgAde8s&sig=Rl_68hxEGcEFWGvxegMKnXaFWKo&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWqtuQhvzLAhWBkg8KHfmMBR4Q6AEIQTAF#v=onepage&q=Supply%20Voltage%20Supervisor%20msp430&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau144j/slau144j.pdf

> A POR is a device reset. A POR is only generated by the following
>   three events:
>
> **• Powering up the device**
>
> • A low signal on the RST/NMI pin when configured in the reset mode
>
> • An SVS low condition when PORON = 1

So if your device does not have Supply Voltage Supervisor only option would be to make your own using ADC.